# Not able to connect to timescaledb with nodejs client running on Lambda

Tags: node.js, postgresql, aws-lambda, timescaledb

I have a timescaledb hosted on aws cloud and I am running my nodejs client on lambda. When I try to connect to timescaledb the connection gets terminated. This is the error which I get in the log

```
ERROR   Unhandled Promise Rejection     
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Connection terminated unexpectedly",
    "reason": {
        "errorType": "Error",
        "errorMessage": "Connection terminated unexpectedly",
        "stack": [
            "Error: Connection terminated unexpectedly",
            "    at Connection.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:255:9)",
            "    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:312:28)",
            "    at Connection.emit (events.js:223:5)",
            "    at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:475:20)",
            "    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:139:10)",
            "    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:228:7)",
            "    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:475:20)",
            "    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1185:12)",
            "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)"
        ]
    },
    "promise": {},
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: Error: Connection terminated unexpectedly",
        "    at process.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)",
        "    at process.emit (events.js:223:5)",
        "    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:475:20)",
        "    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:201:33)",
        "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:32)"
    ]
}
```

This is my code

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
            var pg = require('pg');
                var conString = "postgres://user:pass@host/con?ssl=true";

                var client = new pg.Client(conString);
                client.connect();
                client.query('select * from table', (err, res) => {
                                          console.log(err, res)
                                          client.end()
                                })


};
```

This code works fine when I run it locally but not on lambda. What could be the issue?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you have any information in the server log that could hint at what the issue is?

Comment: The message is given when authentication fails, so you should check that you can log in using the user and password (and SSL) on the machine where you want to execute the query.